# Spring boot + Jackson - Always convert dates to UTC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, java-time, jackson2

I'm saving the dates on my database *without timestamp*, so I want to standarize the way the dates are received by my Spring Boot Rest Controllers, so the services can be deployed anywhere in the world (AWS EC2, etc).

I tried to set the following properties, didn't help:

```
spring.jackson.time-zone=UTC
```

There is another property, which is always `true`, so I didn't set, that is:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.adjust-dates-to-context-time-zone=true
```

I'm deploying to 2 separate Ubuntu containers, one at `UTC` timezone and another in my current timezone `America/Sao_Paulo` which is (GMT -3).

Example payload:

```
{"date":"2017-09-15T18:58:00.000Z"}
```

When the service is deployed on São Paulo, it receives:

```
2017-09-15 18:58:00.000000
```

Which is **correct**.

When the service is deployed on UTC, it receives:

```
2017-09-15 15:58:00.000000
```

Which is **incorrect**.

I'm storing the date information in Java with `LocalDateTime`.

Example model:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

class Model {
    private LocalDateTime date;

    public LocalDateTime getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDateTime date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Example resource:

```
@RestController
class Resource {
    @RequestMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> add(@RequestBody Model model) {
        System.out.println(model.getDate());
        // persistence ommited
        return ResponseEntity.created(URI.create("")).build();
    }
}
```

I cannot change the timezone of all my production machines, I must solve this with Jackson and Java (if possible).

Another restriction: must not annotate my model classes to do this.

My `pom.xml` (relevant part)

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've faced a similar problem in my production environment too.
I've solved it with this method in my Application.java (the class with main method):

```
@PostConstruct
void started() {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
}
```

Hope it could help you.

Comment: I tried this but the problem persists. I get a 3-hour-difference between the servers (which is the difference from UTC to my timezone).

Comment: with this trick you force the conversion of every received date in UTC, so that the received dates are ready to be stored in your database.
In my system i'm not using LocalDateTime but I'm using Date and java.sql.Timestamp.

Comment: Your answer actually works, the problem was my database configuration. Thanks.

Comment: This solution changes the TimeZone for the entire JVM. Meaning that it'll impact other application running on the server, which is not ideal :(

Comment: Java 8 LocalDateTime does not respect time zone and any jackson settings are ignored. Instead use ZondedDateTime, works with Hibernate 5+